# After importing GoogleMaps via CocoaPods unable to sign framework while building project

Tags: ios, google-maps, code-signing, markerclusterer

I'm using GoogleMaps in a project. I wanted to do clustering of markers and I found Google-Maps-iOS-Utils-QuadTree to do that.

At first I got problem with installing the pods due to

```
The 'Pods-ticktack-ios' target has transitive dependencies
that include static binaries (/Users/***/Documents/foo/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework)
```

I solved this by using https://github.com/Reflejo/GoogleMapsPodspec but after pod install and clean & build I got problem code signing of framework.

```
Code Signinge /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/foo-ghjyenrxiaouuffzqbcqxfrbgbvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/foo.app/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework
with Identity iPhone Developer: **** (XXXXXXXX)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN 
--preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements 
"/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/foo-ghjyenrxiaouuffzqbcqxfrbgbvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/foo.app/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework"
/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/foo-ghjyenrxiaouuffzqbcqxfrbgbvb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/foo.app/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework:
bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to reinstall pods, remove Xcode's DerivatedData, but nothing helped. Does anyone have solution for it?

Xcode version is 7.3

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271548/code-sign-error-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835443/xcode-swift-domain-nsposixerrordomain-code-22/26617294#26617294

Comment: yes and it didnt help